# Link directly to compiled resource in asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a script that's basically a "widget" that users embed.

It's got just simple vanilla javascript and doesn't have any require's to other resources. It's located at `/app/assets/javascripts/delivery.js`

What I want to do is have the file get compressed/compiled and then let users link directly to it from a script tag, ie. `<script src="http://example.com/assets/delivery.js"></script>`

But right now...that's a no-go. That file doesn't exist in production.

So, how can I compress that file like any other JS file in the pipeline, and then link directly to it?

Comment: What would be this `link`? Your description is almost the default features of the [asset-pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: It would be `http://example.com/assets/delivery.js`. I'm saying `delivery.js` exists in `/app/assets/javascripts/delivery.js` and I want to be able to link to in in production at `/assets/delivery.js` but when I do that now, I get a "page not found" error.

Comment: I would suggest to place it in the `public/` (assuming it would be in the production mode).

Comment: Right...but then I'm not able to compress the file automatically.

Comment: I guess you are about to compress it just once. There is no way to rely on the asset-pipeline, it merges all the js assets in one file. You can use an external compress service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add

```
 config.assets.precompile += ['delivery.js']
```

to your application.rb, then delivery.js will be treated as a manifest file: it will be precompiled and served up as delivery.js in production. Manifest files are often just a series of `//= require` (or `//= require_directory`) statements, but any javascript they contain will also be added to the generated file.

By default the application.js manifest includes everything - you way want to tweak this so that it doesn't include javascript which is intended only to be served standalone.

Comment: I love you. This has been evading me for days. You win. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your app/assets/javascripts/delivery.js is not among the includes of your top-level "manifest" javascript file, i.e. app/assets/javascripts/application.js. application.js usually includes `//= require_tree .`, so it includes your delivery.js by default. You need to change that. Replace "require_tree" with individual "require" statements for all your assets that you want to have precompiled and combined in the application.js.

Next, update your environment files (config/environments/production.rb for production env) to include your file in the list of precompiled assets:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( delivery.js )
```

Now you'll have it as a separate file in your public/assets directory, compiled and compressed in the same way as application.js. Just keep in mind that it has a digest attached to it's name similarly to your application.js (unless, of course, you serve the files without digests by setting config.assets.digest = false).