# Is there a way to add an exception to the require_tree in a manifest file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Is there a way you can include all files in a directory except one, or all directories except one?  So something like:

```
require_tree . :except 'this_one'
```

Just wondering and can't figure out where the documentation is on the "require_tree" method in the manifest file.

Comment: Just curious - what's your motivation for this?

Comment: the motivation could be something similar to that lovely SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089628/link-directly-to-compiled-resource-in-asset-pipeline, I guess.

Comment: I want to include all of my css files except the print.css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 Sprockets require directives - is there a way to exclude particular files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602393/rails-3-1-sprockets-require-directives-is-there-a-way-to-exclude-particular-fi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the version of your environment the following may be possible:

```
//= require_tree "." exclude: "file1", "file2"
```

See this SO thread: [Rails 3.1 Sprockets require directives - is there a way to exclude particular files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602393/rails-3-1-sprockets-require-directives-is-there-a-way-to-exclude-particular-fi).
Never tried it myself, though.

Comment: This didn't work for me but the `stub` directive mentioned in the link thread did work.

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 5: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)

Answer (score 54):

Instead of

> require_tree . :except 'this_one'

write

> require_tree "."
>
> stub "this_one"