# In RoR, how do I include all JS files in a folder on one page only?

Tags: javascript, file, ruby-on-rails-4, include

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have the following folder of Javascript files

```
app/assets/javascripts/flot/
```

I want all the files in this folder included on only a single page (i.e. only one action from a controller).  Is is possible to do this without hard-coding every file in a javascript_include_tag in my view?  Note, I am NOT interested in answers in which all the JS files get included on every action of the controller.  I only need these files for the view rendered by one action.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a master JS file in that folder and throw in a list of

```
//= require [file name]
```

into the mix so it loads all of them from that list.

Then include the following line in the view you want to use.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "flot/[master file name]" %>
```

[Javascript_Include_Tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)

For example you could name your file `app/assets/javascripts/flot/main.js`

Then the content would be

```
#flot/main.js
//= require_tree .
```

and

```
#your view
...
<%= javascript_include_tag "flot/main" %>
...
```

Then any files added to your flot folder or subfolders would automatically be added to your tree. Just make sure you've excluded the `flot` folder from the `require_tree` in your `application.js` file as explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138559/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-exception-to-the-require-tree-in-a-manifest-file)

Comment: I was trying to get out of hard-coding the list in any part of the application, because if I add new files I have to go back and edit the hard-coded stuff.  I was looking for something that coudl automatically pick up everything in that directory.  Might be a pipe dream.

Comment: Perhaps `//= require_tree .` in that master file in the flot/ directory?

Comment: Ah that is a great idea.  What do I name the file taht I would put that line in?

Comment: you can name it whatever you want, like `main.js` 
Then `//=require_tree .` in `main.js` 
And `<%= javascript_include_tag "flot/main" %>` in your view