# Where to use "//= require" outside application.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error while pushing to production...

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 54152, col: 39, pos: 1560781)
```

I believe the cause is coming from application.js...

```
//= require serviceworker-companion #If I take this line out the error goes away.
//= require_tree .
```

Where else can I put this line `//= require serviceworker-companion` besides in application.js?

I'm using the [serviceworker-rails gem](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails) and it says in the documentation...

> NOTE Given that Service Worker operates in a separate browser thread,
>   outside the context of your web pages, you don't want to include
>   serviceworker.js script in your application.js. So if you have a line
>   like require_tree . in your application.js file, you'll either need to
>   move your serviceworker.js to another location or replace require_tree
>   with something more explicit.

I need `require_tree .` so where else can I move serviceworker.js?

I've been reading the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and I'm still not sure where else these references lines `//=` can go besides application.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the second half of that note: "or replace require_tree with something more explicit." the issue should be solvable by removing `//= require serviceworker-companion` from the tree.

You can acomplish that by adding an exception to the tree in the following way:

(In `aplication.js`)

After

```
//= require serviceworker-companion
//= require_tree .
```

add

```
//= stub "serviceworker-companion"
```

See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138559/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-exception-to-the-require-tree-in-a-manifest-file) for more info on adding an exception to the tree.

I tested this on a different gem and it worked, Let me know if it helps you!